# Does this strong regularity property hold?

Tags: set-theory

A common result regarding regular cardinals is the following strong closure property:

> **Theorem**: If $\pi$ is a regular cardinal, then, for every function $f: \pi \to \pi$, there is some nonzero ordinal $\gamma < \pi$ so that $\forall \delta < \gamma (f(\delta) < \gamma)$.

This follows easily from $\textrm{cof}(\pi) = \pi$. Now, akin to the step from "every normal function has a fixed point" to "every class of normal functions has common fixed points", could we characterize the following *stronger* property of regular cardinals?

> **Conjecture**: If $\pi$ is a regular cardinal, then for every finite set $F$ of functions $\pi \to \pi$, there is some nonzero ordinal $\gamma < \pi$ so that $\forall \delta < \gamma \forall f \in F (f(\delta) < \gamma)$.

Comment: This is very easy to prove once you know that the set of closure points is a club.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F=\{f_\alpha:\pi\to\pi\mid \alpha<\delta\}$ for some $\delta<\pi$.

Let $G=\{g_\alpha:\pi\to\pi\mid \alpha<\delta\}$ where $g_\alpha(x)=\max(\sup f_\alpha''x, x)$.

Lastly, let $C=\{c_\alpha\subseteq\pi\mid \alpha<\delta\}$ where $c_\alpha$ is the set of $g_\alpha$-fixed point.

Each $c_\alpha$ is a club, so $\bigcap C$ is a club, but if $x\in \bigcap C$ it is the fixed point of all of $g_\alpha$, hence $f_\alpha'' x\subseteq x$